# Is it possible/okay to snapshot (mock) a given function in NodeJS in order to have faster tests or local development environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, integration-testing

*I'm desperately trying to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.*

**Some context** (This is the best use case I could come up with):

Imagine you have a codebase that uses Google Search in order to crawl websites for different search queries inside the web. Meaning you have an API endpoint that takes a search query and will save the HTML of all the websites that Google returns inside the database and then return them as the result of your API query.

Of course, such a system is not a real-time system, because of the network requests being made. So you cannot return the results right away. You may start with a `Request Recieved` response in the beginning and then the system just does its job of downloading HTML and saving it inside the DB.

Another thing that is important, is the fact that some websites might be broken, meaning you cannot wait forever for a response, so you set a timeout on your request and cancel the promise after a certain time.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const getHTMLOfWebsite = async (websiteURL: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(websiteURL);
  return data;
};

export const getHTMLOfWebsiteWithTimeout = (websiteURL: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getHTMLOfWebsite(websiteURL).then(resolve, reject);
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error('Timeout'));
    }, 30 * 1000);
  });
};
```

Now If you want to test such a system, or run it on your local machine, you have a big problem. which is that every time you wanna test it, your machine will start its fans and suck the network bandwidth and take 2 - 3 minutes in order to give you the result for the query that you just made. This will hinder development time and make your integration tests flaky.

So my question is what is the proper way to handle such a scenario, both for testing and local development.

**What I've tried:**

So the first thing that I thought was that any request that goes outside of the codebase needs to be mocked because third-party APIs are not part of our codebase, This means the Google API, all of the websites, and the returning HTML for each of them need to be mocked. However doing this by hand is very cumbersome, so I found [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock#nock-back). Basically what this package does is that it will record all the requests being made from your NodeJS process and will save them inside a file, later when you make the same requests it will check if the JSON file does include that request, if it does, then it will just return the recorded response.

This is great! however there is a problem, earlier we talked about `timeout` or `failed` requests. Nock does not record such requests because they are not requests really, they do not have a response, they are just a function that throws after a certain timeout is reached.

So what I did later was that I tried to implement a version of `Nock`, not for HTTP requests but for promises.

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';
import { set } from 'lodash';

const deserialize = (serializedJavascript: string) => {
  return eval('(' + serializedJavascript + ')');
};

let areFixturesLoaded = false;

const funcHashToFixturesMap: Record<string, any> = {};

const fixturesFolder = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './fixtures');

export const provideMockOnTest = (func: any): any => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'local' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    return func;
  }

  if (!areFixturesLoaded) {
    areFixturesLoaded = true;
    const fixtureFolderExists = fs.existsSync(fixturesFolder);

    if (!fixtureFolderExists) {
      fs.mkdirSync(fixturesFolder);
    }

    const funcs = fs.readdirSync(fixturesFolder);

    for (const cachedFunctionHash of funcs) {
      const unparsedJSON = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(fixturesFolder, cachedFunctionHash)).toString();
      const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(unparsedJSON);
      funcHashToFixturesMap[cachedFunctionHash] = parsedJSON;
    }
  }

  const cypher = crypto.createHash('sha256');

  cypher.update(func.toString());

  const funcDigest = cypher.digest('hex');

  return async (...args: any[]) => {
    const joinedArgs = serialize(args);

    const cachedValue = funcHashToFixturesMap?.[funcDigest]?.[joinedArgs];

    if (cachedValue) {
      if (cachedValue.resolved) {
        return deserialize(cachedValue.resolved);
      }
      throw deserialize(cachedValue.reject);
    }

    const newCache: Record<string, any> = {};

    try {
      const newFuncResult = await func(...args);
      newCache['resolved'] = serialize(newFuncResult);
    } catch (e) {
      newCache['reject'] = serialize(e);
    }

    set(funcHashToFixturesMap, `${funcDigest}.${joinedArgs}`, newCache);

    await fs.promises.writeFile(path.resolve(fixturesFolder, funcDigest), JSON.stringify(newCache));

    if (newCache.resolved) {
      return deserialize(newCache.resolved);
    }

    throw deserialize(newCache.reject);
  };
};
```

Now I will export my `getHTMLOfWebsiteWithTimeout` like so:

```js
export const getHTMLOfWebsiteWithTimeoutAndMockProvided = provideMockOnTest(getHTMLOfWebsiteWithTimeout);
```

However I'm not really sure if this is the right approach to achieve what I'm after.

I searched a lot in order to find a package that does this as I imagine this is a common problem however I didn't find anything.

Comment: Question: Do you always need to test the entire thing? Wouldn't it be better to have unit tests for web page parser (i.e.  a google research page) and a web  page downloader is able to handle failed requests? What exactly can you do once a request fails? What do you gain by integration tests, esp. if mocked? The apparent benefit of faster test speed comes at the trade-off that you wouldn't know when your external dependencies break (Google changes their response page).

Comment: That being said: Faster test speed might exactly be worth it. I did a similar thing with a booking api. We completely mocked their output in order to repeatedly test our booking flow. That way, I could always ensure that a flow would work. Of course, if the booking-api did a breaking change, my test would be meaningless (they would be green unless I updated the mock and fixed it) but that was ok. As the test was not for ensuring the correctness of the application but the correctness of the flow ASSUMING the api gives a certain output.

Comment: With respect to what I do when a request fails, I will call a certain function and record the failure somewhere. (The flow of failure must also be tested). It is really not important if third-party dependencies break, that will be reported later by QA. However, it is important for the developer (e.g: myself) to make sure the change that they've made (e.g: store failures in the DB, store the number of href tags, or any other feature)  is working. As you have said it is important to test the "Flow". It is also important for these mocks to be generated **automatically**.

Comment: In terms of unit tests, I'm not really sure. What I'm trying to achieve here is **black-box testing**, and also increase the speed of development by **memoizing** (?) the time-consuming part of the code in the development environment. (e.g: developers using postman to test the feature that they have developed). So developers don't need to go and grab a cup of coffee every time they added a `console.log` or some piece of new code to the codebase just because running the whole thing takes a lot of time.