# How to know if a function definition has been changed in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I'm trying to write a caching system for some time-intensive functions (Network requests/computation heavy) and I need to generate a fingerprint from the functions in order to invalidate the cached results once a developer changes the functions.

I have tried the following approach to generate the fingerprint:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const generateFingerprintOfFunc = (inputFunc) => {
  const cypher = crypto.createHash('sha256');

  cypher.update(inputFunc.toString());

  return cypher.digest('hex');
}
```

However, the problem with this approach is that the fingerprint won't be changed once the developer changes any of the functions that are called inside the function that is being fingerprinted because that function's definition hasn't really changed.

```js
const foo = () => {
  return bar() + 1;
}

const bar = () => {
  return 1;
}


const fingerprintOfFoo = generateFingerprintOfFunc(foo); // 489290d22f653965a59e2e5fbb7b626535babd660f7f49501fc88c3e7fbc0176
```

Now I will change the `bar` function:

```js
const foo = () => {
    return bar() + 1;
  }

const bar = () => {
    return 10;
}

const fingerprintOfFoo = generateFingerprintOfFunc(foo); // 489290d22f653965a59e2e5fbb7b626535babd660f7f49501fc88c3e7fbc0176
```

As you can see the fingerprint has not changed while the return value of the function has.

Why do I need to do this?

I'm trying to generate dynamic and automatic mocks for my expensive functions during development and testing. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483614/is-it-possible-okay-to-snapshot-mock-a-given-function-in-nodejs-in-order-to-ha) SO Question

Comment: I don't see a practical way to do this at runtime (or a need, unless you're updating a running system). You could walk the AST at build time, but if you're doing that, it'd just be easier to invalidate all the caches and start over anyway. You could conceivably hide all of this behind prototypes and for every call you aggregate the class's (essentially) version info, but... tbh I only barely see the point. Seems like it'd be a lot easier to just warm the caches on startup.

Comment: But I don't wanna invalid the caches unless the functions are changed. I was thinking maybe I could use `git` to somehow implement this. I think jest does this somehow.

Comment: Jest records running the output of renders into a file which can be compared against subsequent runs, and can indicate differences, meaning either the code broke, or the snapshot needs to be updated. There's no way to use Git for this as-is because again, you would need to walk the actual AST (with the caveat that static analysis could miss dynamic behavior) to determine if a function has changed (and then you'd need to determine functional vs stylistic changes).

Comment: I'm talking about the caching system of jest, not the snapshots, jest has a mode that will only run tests related to file changes. I believe jest knows what files each test needs and will check whether any of those files are changed otherwise it will just pass the test if it has been passed before and not run the actual test.

Comment: I don't think this problem can ever be reliably solved from the outside.  Instead, you'd rather the developer of the function often some sort of version stamp so you can see if the cache was built with the same version as is now running and, if not, clear the cache.  The developer could offer a property on their function as in `generateFingerprintOfFunc.version = 1`.  When you start a cache, you record what version is corresponds to.  Anytime you run again, you see if the current version matches what your cache was built with.

Comment: @jfriend00 But it would be so damn awesome if this was done automatically!

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you please elaborate on "with the caveat that static analysis could miss dynamic behavior"?

Comment: Sure, I'm just suggesting that there is no such way to do that reliably.  You can't possibly know what did or didn't change inside the function and how that affects various values that might come out of the function based on various input.

Comment: If you know all the files a developer could change and just want to know if there is any change at all, you could just compare all of them against their hashes (or a Git repo). You cannot differntiate between single functions though with this approach. Otherwise you would need to parse and go through all the imported code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't want it to be very sophisticated. We can count even a single space or a comment as a change as well. We do force specific formatting in our codebase using `eslint`. So formattings don't really get changed. And added comments or any other change is alright too. I can even go as far as, finding the file of each function and making sure nothing in that file has changed suffices in this use case.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I like the idea of "Parse and go through all the imported code". Why is that bad? If going through the code is different from actually running the code then that isn't a bad idea at all.

Comment: OK, then just hash the source file or relevant portion of the source file if you have access to that and can trust that you know what part of the file is relevant.  I don't know what you expect from us as you pretty much counter anything we say with what you already want to do.  It sounds like you just want to go do that.

Comment: That's the problem, I wanna know if there is a way that `v8` would give me the path of the files making up a certain function and all of its internals.

Comment: Probably, at least the debug build. Easier to parse it yourself since there are frameworks to help. But you are over-confident in the ease of determining functional differences. Since it’s unlikely you’re modifying a running system, it’s still *significantly* easier to simply warm the caches on startup. If this is even a problem worth solving. Even a file hash based solution, ignoring method-level changes, would still require complete static analysis (including any external dependencies), and that still wouldn’t handle runtime changes.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna know if there is a way that v8 would give me the path of the files making up a certain function and all of its internals.

No.

It can't. JavaScript is too dynamic.

Consider this example:

```js
let helper;

const foo = () => helper() + 1;

const bar = () => 1;
const baz = () => 2;

helper = bar;
```

So far, this does the same as your example. Now suppose someone either changed the last line to read, or added a new line that reads `helper = baz`. In that case, no function's definition has changed, but `foo`'s behavior has! In fact, one can take that same idea to construct an even simpler case:

```js
let global = 42;
const foo = () => global;
```

If someone changes `global` (whether statically in the source, or dynamically), `foo`'s return value will change, but no function definition will. In case of dynamic assignment, not even anything in the source will change. And of course such an assignment could depend on arbitrary conditions/circumstances, such as user interaction, time of day, `Math.random()`, whatever.

In general, the only way (for anyone, including the engine) to figure out what a function will return is to execute it.
Memoization works if developers carefully choose functions that lend themselves to memoization.
An automated system that takes any arbitrary function (without imposing any limitations on what the function does) and memoizes it, or determines whether it will the same value as last time, *without actually executing it*, is impossible to create in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "changes the function"? As in, you have jest in watch mode and want to only pick up changes when they make fundamental changes? I think the real question is why this is necessary, to begin with.

1. How are you generating dynamic mocks? Does this imply that you repeatedly creating these mocks in real-time with network requests? Then they aren't really mocks. You are just making real requests and then deciding to temporarily store it somewhere. You could just skip that data-saving step and your resulting testing process would be identical. That's a glorified integration test
2. I guess others can disagree, but your unit testing philosophy seems a little flawed. Dynamic mocks imply that you have no control over what situation ends up getting tested. If you are not in full control of your mocks, couldn't you end up testing the exact same case (or edge case) repeatedly? That's a waste of resources and can lead to flawed tests. Covering all of your intended cases would happen by coincidence, as opposed to explicit intent. Your unit tests should be deterministic. Not stochastic.

It seems like you need to solve your testing methodology, as opposed to accepting that your tests are slow and developing strategies on how to work around it.